# I'm trying to export data from a MySQL Workbench to a csv, but it keeps converting specific column values to scientific notation

Tags: mysql

I want to export a fairly large dataset 190K+ observations to a csv and it keeps converting values in a specific column to scientific notation. It's only happening to values that are greater than 11 characters. The datatype of the column is a VARCHAR.

When I export the data, this is what it looks like:

```
State_ID
43357026001
43476887001
5.10E+11
51034543453
5.11E+12
100274530A
ZZ467893
```

But, this is what I want it to look like:

```
State_ID
43357026001
43476887001
510392938483
51034543453
5114657382831
100274530A
ZZ467893
```

What is going on, and how can I export the data so there is no scientific notation. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you use VARCHAR data type for int values??? You can use all this types https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html

Comment: Do you export manually (via the 'Wizard') or are executing a SELECT *FROM table INTO OUTFILE 'table.csv' in the MySQL Workbench?

Comment: as you are already in mysql workbench use the data export manager

Answer (score 0):

for testing purposes is tab1 the table with your column

```
SELECT *
FROM tab1 
  INTO OUTFILE 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/file.csv'
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

works just fine and exports the column as text

or you use

[image: Table Data Export Manager]

and change nothing in the following steps, it will give the same result as teh comand